# Dynamic resource not updating ImageButton style in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I defined two ContentPage level styles to be bound dynamically to an ImageButton. When the ImageButton click event is called, it is supposed to switch the ImageButton style, but this is not happening.

Below is the ContentPage content with the styles and the ImageButton definition:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleMobile.SamplePage"
             Title="">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="defaultStyle" TargetType="ImageButton">
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Grey"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="selectedStyle" TargetType="ImageButton">
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="50, 100, 5, 100, 5, 50, 100, 100, 100" ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *, *"
          Padding="25, 35, 25, 35" ColumnSpacing="5" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="mobileNetworks">

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Text="Select Network"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <ImageButton Source="first.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="10" Clicked="SelectImage" Style="{DynamicResource imageButtonStyle}"/>
        <ImageButton Source="second.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BorderColor="Grey" CornerRadius="10"/>
        <ImageButton Source="third.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BorderColor="Grey" CornerRadius="10"/>
        <ImageButton Source="fourth.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BorderColor="Grey" CornerRadius="10"/>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Below is the code behind file where the first style is set, and the second style is set inside the click event handler:

```
public partial class SamplePage : ContentPage
{
    public SamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Resources["imageButtonStyle"] = Resources["defaultStyle"];
    }

    private void SelectImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Resources["imageButtonStyle"] = Resources["selectedStyle"];
    
    }
}
```

I'm still trying to find what is wrong, and why it is not working as expected.

Comment: I would recommend using Visual States (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states) or Triggers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers) for this instead.

Comment: Okay @ewerspej, I would read through it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

First give the ImageButton a name like this `x:Name="Image1"`

I added 2 Buttons to change it and go back.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="defaultStyle" TargetType="ImageButton">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="selectedStyle" TargetType="ImageButton">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
    </Frame>
    <ImageButton x:Name="Image1"  Source="balzwart.png" Style="{DynamicResource defaultStyle}" />

    <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    <Button Text="Back" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
</StackLayout>
```

and for the Button Click

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.Style = (Style)Resources["selectedStyle"];
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.Style = (Style)Resources["defaultStyle"];
    }
```

[image]

Find it here https://github.com/borisoprit/DynamicSO

Comment: For some reason, I tried it, and it is still not updating the style when clicked.

Comment: I put the project on Github to compare . https://github.com/borisoprit/DynamicSO

Comment: What you did, was the exact thing I did, but not I'm not getting same result you got. Could it be because you are using Xamarin, and I am using .net maui?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manipulating the styles at runtime, *which is only a semi-good idea and should be done differently anyway*, I recommend you do something like below instead using Visual States and only one Style for the ImageButton:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SelectedImageSample.MainPage">

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="ImageButton">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
          <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Blue" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Grid RowDefinitions="50, 100, 5, 100, 5, 50, 100, 100, 100" ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *, *"
        Padding="25, 35, 25, 35" ColumnSpacing="5" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="mobileNetworks">

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
           Text="Select Network"
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <ImageButton Source="first.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderWidth="2"  HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="10" Clicked="SelectImage" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>
    <ImageButton Source="second.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="10" Clicked="SelectImage" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>
    <ImageButton Source="third.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="10" Clicked="SelectImage" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>
    <ImageButton Source="fourth.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="10" Clicked="SelectImage" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>

  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

In your Code Behind, you then can use the event handler to set the Visual State as follows:

```cs
private void SelectImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ImageButton imageButton)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(imageButton, "Selected");
    }
}
```

This is just the minimal demonstration of how it can be done without manipulating a style in the resources. If you want to unselect the `ImageButton` again, you'll need to implement some logic and an **Unselected** Visual State.

**Update 1**

It might be useful to store some kind of state on the button by adding an `IsSelected` property (e.g. via inheritance). Then the Visual State can be updated accordingly.

**Update 2**

If you don't want to extend `ImageButton`, you could also use an [Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties) to store the state for the button.

Comment: It should. I hope it suits your use case. You may need to introduce state if you want to be able to change it back again.

Comment: This didn't work. I might need to do some further digging deep to find out why. So far so good, anything that intends to change the style of elements during runtime is not working, and the documentation says DynamicResource is the way to change it, but that isn't working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml#dynamic-styles

Comment: I've tried this myself with your example code and it works fine for me. Can you specify what exactly didn't work? DynamicResources are okay if you want to change an entire Theme or have other kinds of dependencies that can change a Style at runtime. However, this is costly and manipulating Resources from within the code behind for this is not ideal. Visual States and Style Triggers are more common approaches for your kind of problem.

Comment: Using the VisualStateGroup as you specified, the styles did not changed. I put a breakpoint in the code, and the button clicked event handler was called, and nothing changed. I went as far as updating my dotnet SDK from 6.0.401 to 6.0.4.02, just incase there might be some unknown bug, but nothing changed.

Comment: It does work. I've created a repository from the code that I used for the example in my solution: https://github.com/ewerspej/visual-states-sample. Which platform are you debugging this on?